# Static resource get files from zip

Tags: apex, static-resources, pagereference, zip

I want to give files from zip in static resource. How can i do it? It gives me 404 on getContent() anyway: with file ending(png,txt, etc) and without.

```
    PageReference pageRef = PageReference.forResource('Zip','File.csv');
    PageReference contentRef = new PageReference(pageRef.getUrl().split('\\?')[0]);
    
    System.debug(contentRef.getContent());
```

Tried another way but same error.Link without File.csv is valid and i can download that file.

```
StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id,SystemModstamp FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'Zip'];
String srPath = '/resource/' + sr.SystemModstamp.getTime() + '/Zip/File.csv'; 
PageReference pg = new PageReference(srPath);
String body = pg.getContent().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt work with 7z. Didn't pay attention to it. With zip works good.